# kendo grid foreign column selected text being overrriden by client template

Tags: kendo-ui, grid, selected

I have a kendo grid on MVC proeject with a foreignKey column with a client template on the same column to send the data to the controller (hidden) as I have a header information just above the kendo grid that i want to send to the controller. Everything works fine. But when I select the dropdown in the grid it displays the value rather than the text.

```
columns.ForeignKey(c => c.studentId, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Students"], "Id", "name")
    .Title("id - name")
    .Width(70)
    .ClientTemplate("#= studentId #" + "<'input type='hidden'  name='MyModel[#= index(data)#].StudentId' value='#= StudentId #' />");
```

The above is the exact code I currently have.

How can I show the user the selected text (name in this case) rather than the value(Id in this case) on the kendo grid.

Thanks

Comment: Ever figure out a solution? I have the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just had the same problem and found this on the [telerik site](http://www.telerik.com/forums/displaying-foreign-key-value-in-clientrowtemplate-of-kendoui-grid):

Basically create a function that looks up the text from Foreign Key Drop Down in the grid.

```
 columns.ForeignKey(c => c.G_ID, plus, "Value", "Text").Title("Plu").Lockable(true).ClientFooterTemplate("Total").ClientTemplate("#= getTextByValue(data)#" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='Schedules[#= index(data)#].G_ID' value='#= G_ID #' />"); //.Hidden();
```

and the javascript:

```
var collection;
```

And the function:

```
function getTextByValue(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var dGrid = $("#the-dtl-grid").data("kendoGrid");
    //change the index of the column with your index
    valuesCollection = dGrid.options.columns[1].values;

    //if the collection is empty - get it from the grid
    if (!collection) {
        collection = {};
        //Set the correct FKColumn index
        for (var value in valuesCollection) {
            collection[valuesCollection[value].value] = valuesCollection[value].text;
        }
    }
    return collection[data.G_ID];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, very helpfull. Just in my case I must change this row `valuesCollection = dGrid.options.columns[1].values;` to `valuesCollection = dGrid.columns[1].values;`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.